# pattern matching on constants

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming, pattern-matching

So I have these constant FilePath variables (strings)

```
s1 , s2 , s3 , s4 ... :: Filepath
s1 = "help.txt"
s2 = "sljdfn"
-- ...
```

And I have a function that takes one of these filepaths and returns a int.

```
positionInList:: Filepath -> Int
positionInList s1 = 1
positionInList s2 = 2
-- ...
```

However when compiling I get pattern match redundant warning and the program behaves wierd, so I think this is the problem. How would I be able to solve this ?

Comment: You cannot match arbitrary things like that. Each line is just equivalent to `positionInList _ = 1`, `positionInList _ = 2` etc. If you're willing to not use pattern matching, use `indexOf`.

Comment: The compiler here sees `s1` and `s2` in your `positionInList` as variables.

Comment: uhu I see, will you index of or something simular thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `==` here:

```
positionInList:: Filepath -> Int
positionInList s | s == s1 = 1
                 | s == s2 = 2
.....
```

Otherwise, `positionInList s1 = ...` introduces `s1` as a local variable, as the `x` in `positionInList x = ...`, matching any string.

Alternatively, use the library functions:

```
import Data.List

positionInList:: Filepath -> Int
positionInList s = case elemIndex s [s1,s2,s3,....] of
   Just pos -> pos+1
   Nothing  -> error "positionInList: not found!"
```

Perhaps it would be even better to make `positionInList` to return `Maybe Int`, unless you have a sensible default when the file path is not found.

Answer (score 3):

If you use:

```
positionInList:: Filepath -> Int
positionInList s1 = 1
positionInList s2 = 2
```

Haskell will treat `s1` and `s2` just as variables (that shadow an existing binding). So that means your function here will *always* return `1`.

Haskell however has already a function to obtain the index in a list [**`elemIndex :: a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex), you can thus define your `positionInList` with:

```
import Data.List(elemIndex)

positionInList :: FilePath -> Maybe Int
positionInList = fmap (1+) . flip elemIndex [s1, s2]
```

The `fmap (1+)` here will map the zero-based indices to one-based indices.

Returning a `Maybe a` such that we can use `Nothing` is usually more idiomatic Haskell than returning a value like `-1`. We can however use [**`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`**](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=fromMaybe&scope=set%3Astackage) in case you want to map `Nothing` on some other value, like:

```
import Data.List(elemIndex)
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

positionInList :: FilePath -> Int
positionInList = fromMaybe (-1) . fmap (1+) . flip elemIndex [s1, s2]
```